# querying in django

Tags: database, django, postgresql, django-views

I have stored data in the table with respect to dates ie there could be more than one entry for the same month, but when i retrieve them i need to get them as combined result. So is there anyway that i could query it to retrieve the data for a month that is set the range as month in django(view).

*edit:*

Modifications from my prev post. I need to do it for a year and i do not have a specific start date and end date. I need to set the range for months in a year irrespective of the number of days present. my database would look like this:

```
date        count1     count2  
2011/12/01,   12,          3 
2011/12/03,   3,           6
```

Now i need to retrieve count1 for the month of december. I need a generic query not just for a particular month with say 30 or 31 or 28 days.

Comment: show us your model so that we can help

Comment: You shouldn't be asking a new question using edit. If the question was answered, mark it as answered and post a new question. Also try to be more specific in your question titles. "Querying in django" doesn't tell people that you are looking for a range query. Typing a specific question title also helps you determine if the question you are about to ask has been asked before.

Comment: @kriegar its not a different question. I just tried adding a few more details to the same .

Comment: It is a different question. First you asked how to make a query for the "data." Then you asked how to get the count. Anyways edited my answer to get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

[**`docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range)

Assuming you have a DateField

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_date = models.DateField()
```

query:

```
import datetime
startdate = datetime.date(...start of some month...)
enddate = datetime.date(...end of some month...)
my_model_in_range = MyModel.objects.filter(my_date__range(startdate,enddate))
```

**edit:**

[**`count docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count)

```
import datetime

def first_day_of_month(month, year):
    return datetime.date(year, month, 1)

def last_day_of_month(month, year):
    return datetime.date(year, month+1, d.day) - datetime.timedelta(1)

# if you want query for jan 2009: month = 1, year = 2009

first = first_day_of_month(1, 2009)
last = last_day_of_month(1, 2009)

objects_in_jan_2009 = MyModel.objects.filter(my_date__range(first, last))

count = objects_in_jan_2009.count()
```

Answer (score 1):

After you receive you range, query you model with the following:

```
YouModel.objects.filter(date__gt='initial date').filter(date__lt='final date')
```

date should be a field in your model. the __gt and __lt aply a filter for the field to search for values greater and lesser than the parameter passed.

Comment: gte and lte might be more appropriate for dates unless you want to calculate a day before and after.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is through raw sql

```
YourModel.objects.extra(
        select={'values':'select sum(count) as count , extract(month from mymodel_db.date) as date group by date'}
```